# Animating a table on load with falling cells similar to tetris

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

Is it possible to have table cells fall from the top of the screen to populate a table on load using jquery/css animations?

My table spans the entire view (15x15 cells), with each cell having a unique ID.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research?  we are going to need more information then this stack overflow isn't a code writing service you have to have a go at this problem yourself then if you run into issues/bugs then this is the place to ask

Answer (score 1):

what have you tried so far?

Possible *basic example: it uses `position`,  `transition` and no `id`s*

```js
function delay() {
  var AnDelay = 11.25;// longest delay
  for (let e of document.getElementsByClassName("cell")) {
    e.classList.add("reset");
    AnDelay = AnDelay - 0.05;// decrease transition delay
    e.style.transitionDelay = AnDelay + "s";
  }
}
window.onload = delay;
```

```css
td.cell {
  border: solid;
  padding: 0.2vh;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 150vh;
  right: -20vw;
  transition: 1s;
}
td.cell:nth-child(odd) {
  right: 20vw;
}
td.cell.reset {/* transition delayed to go back to position*/
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
kbd {/* demo use */
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button
}
```

```html
<p>Hit <kbd>run code snippet</kbd> to run it again</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Where are you failing ?

---

Please provide your own piece of code . **This answer is morelike a comment.**